# Cannot use DynamicObject in net standard 1.6 class library project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, dynamicobject, .net-standard

Refer to the screenshot below, I need to use `DynamicObject` in `.net standard 1.6 library project`.

However, I cannot add any additional dependencies by right click the `Dependencies` and `Add Reference` in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.2).

Does anyone know how to use `DynamicObject` in `.net standard class library project` targeting `netstandard 1.6`?

[image]

Comment: You'll have to add the Nuget package, System.Dynamic.Runtime.  Not so "standard" anymore after doing this, afaict it also adds ILGeneration and that's not compatible with the kind of platform targets that don't have a jitter.  YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `System.Dynamic.Runtime` NuGet package for the type to become available in the `System.Dynamic` namespace. In `netstandard2.0`, it will be available automatically.

```
dotnet add package System.Dynamic.Runtime
```